# I want to make an openid login using java servlets

Tags: java, servlets, openid

I want to make a open-id login for my web site, like Stack Overflow.

The login may contain 3 or 4 options to chose from for e.g. Facebook, Google etc.

I'm using java (servlet) for server side scripting. Can anyone give me a direction or starting point for the same?

Comment: Did you even try to ask your favorite search engine?

Comment: @home hey i really searched on google but it was little over the top for me as i'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you. Look for java libraries

http://openid.net/developers/libraries/

Answer (score 2):

I don't find this question as invalid as others seems to simply because many previous answers are outdated and I would like to see some peoples opinions about best practice for this.

I myself would probably go with http://agorava.org/ if one wants to do more then login. It seems to be a promising project and I predict a bright future for CDI.

But for openid I'm curious about what experiences others had.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search yielded this: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID
and this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ and http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/